# improve python performance in networkx

Tags: python, performance, numpy, networkx

I am creating a network in python using the packages `numpy` and networks. Here is the code that I need help with:

```
def create_rt_network(self):                                                                                                       
    """construct a retweet network from twitter db"""                                                                                                                                                                        
    con = mdb.connect(**proper-information**)                                                                                                                                                                                            
    cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)                                                                                       
    cur.execute("select COUNT(*) from users")                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    N = cur.fetchone()['COUNT(*)']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    mat = np.empty((N, N))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    #read adjacency table and store data into mat                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    cur.execute("select * from adjacency")                                                                                                                                                                               
    rows = cur.fetchall() 

    for row in rows:                                                                                                                                                             
        curRow = row['r']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        curCol = row['c']                                                                                                                                                         
        weight = row['val']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        mat[curRow][curCol] = weight                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    cur.close()                                                                                                                                                                                              
    con.close()      

    g = nx.from_numpy_matrix(mat, create_using=nx.DiGraph())                                                                                            
    return g
```

Facts:

1. Creating this graph takes about an hour
2. table `adjacency` holds 212,000 rows

As I am new to python, I do not how much optimization (if any) the interpreter performs. Regardless, I think the error is in actually creating the graph in the line:

`g = nx.from_numpy_matrix(mat, create_using=nx.DiGraph())`

I believe this because:

1. I have ran the code without that line and it was fast (at most 10 seconds)
2. I think writing `mat` is O(nlgn) as we have n rows, reading from a database (btree search) is O(lgn), and writing `mat` is O(1).

I just had the thought that reading the adjacency matrix takes O(n^2) time; perhaps an adjacency list (which is implemented as a dict of dicts in `networkx`) would be faster. In that case does anyone know about weighted graphs and adjacency lists in networkx?

Let me know if you would like more information, all help is greatly appreciated!
**NOTE:** For the future: How can I know if an hour is reasonable?

Comment: have you tried profiling it? http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/

Comment: Try first to manually find where the bottleneck is. Is it in `nx.from_numpy_matrix()` or the loop?

Comment: Definitely the `nx.from_numpy_matrix()`. It runs in at most 10 seconds without that statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why this is slow when converting a numpy matrix to Di-Graph. Please try this approach below and see if it helps.

```
def create_directed_graph(rows):
    g = nx.DiGraph()
    for row in rows:
        curRow = row['r']
        curCol = row['c']
        weight = row['val']
        g.add_edge(curRow,curCol,Weight=weight)
    return g
```

Comment: That was dumb of me! I was right in the sense that it does take a long time O(n^2) to read an adjacency matrix.